FilamentPHP - How to set component attribute dynamically
I have a form that consists of text input and select components.
And I want to update select component maxItem attribute dynamically based on the text input value.
Is there any way to do that?
Here's what I've done
Forms\Components\Section::make('Petugas')
 ->schema([
    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('person_num')
        ->label('Jumlah Petugas')
        ->required()
        ->default(0)
        ->rules(['min:1'])
        ->live()
        ->numeric(),
    Forms\Components\Select::make('users')
        ->label('Petugas')
        ->relationship('users', 'name')
        ->maxItems(fn (Get $get): int => $get('person_num'))
        ->multiple()
        ->searchable()
        ->preload()
        ->required()
        ->live()
        ->afterStateUpdated(function (Set $set, Get $get, $state): void {
            if (count($state) > $get('person_num')) {
                Notification::make()
                    ->title('Jumlah petugas sudah melebihi jumlah yang diinginkan')
                    ->danger()
                    ->send();
            }

            if (count($state) == $get('person_num')) {
                $set('status', 'close');
            } else {
                $set('status', 'open');
            }
        }),
])->columns(2),

